# Export to .dbf changes my data in ArcMap 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel, dbf

I have an excel table with parcel ID's (PINs).  The PINs are in "number" format in excel.  Iimported this excel table into ArcMap with the goal of joining them with the county parcel shapefile.  I right click on the excel table>export>navigate to myfolder and save as a .dbf.  I add the .dbf to my map and the data is not correct.  When I export, my numbers change. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Using floating-point values for primary keys is a sure-fire way to mangle data. Excel isn't a database application; using it like one often causes this sort of problem.

Comment: Can you add a before-and-after example?

Comment: Try adding and "A" or some other arbitrary value to the front of each value in excel then run the "Excel to Table" tool in ArcMap.  Arc will bring in the values as text because of the "A".  You can then remove the "A" using the field calculator and indexing,  I think "[1:]"  would pull everything except the "A" from each string.  Then if you want it as an integer, add a new field of type integer and cast the string as an int using field calculator again like so.  new Int field = int(!string field!).  The Issue you are facing is how ArcMap/Excel deal with Quantative Vs. Qualitative data.

Comment: That seems to be the issue.  I added the values as "text" and the numbers came in correctly and did not distort. I then added a field as a non-string format and used the field calculator to calculate the values. That fixed the problem.

Comment: @ShelbyEgan Maybe a good idea to post what you did as an answer if it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I imported the excel file with the parcel values as "text" format.  After exporting this field to a dbase, I opened my attribute table, added a "double" type field, used the Field Calculator to equal this to the text field containing my parcels (new double field=text field from original excel file).  This seemed to work without changing the values of my data and I was able to perform the join.